# Powerbuilder word OLE: Run time error 35 while setformresult

Tags: ole, powerbuilder

I am using powerbuilder 12.5 to add data to word templates using bookmarks.When I use objword.setformresult(bookmarkname,value) I get run time error 35

"error calling external object function setformresult"

Info: We have recently migrated powerbuilder 6.5 to 12.5 but still we use Office 2003

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
lole_word = CREATE OLEObject
lole_word.ConnectToNewObject ("word.application")
lole_Document = lole_word.Documents.Open (is_infile,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
lole_range = lole_document.Bookmarks.item(ls_bookmark).Range
lole_range.Text = ls_newText
```

Always put code like this a Try..Catch block and catch OleRuntimeError and RuntimeError. Note that replacing the text will remove the bookmark. If you need the bookmark you have to remember where it is (for example `lole_document.Bookmarks.item(ls_bookmark).Start`) and add the bookmark to the document again.

Comment: Program successfully connects to word application and reads through the bookmarks.The error occurs when updating the bookmar with data.

Comment: What's the error you get? Are you sure ls_newText isn't NULL?

Comment: this error happens because the template bookmarks where created as fields not as plain bookmarks.